# Getting a QPushButton to perform 2 actions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

Preface: I am working on a flashcard app in PyQt5 and I am trying to have an "Enter" button do an action that compares 2 strings by calling a function(one of which from the textEdit box, the other from a list of strings that I have pre coded.) Secondly, I want it to show the comparison as "Right or wrong" by calling the checkanswer() function, but when I press the button and try to get it to call a different function, it will repeat the same behavior from checkanswer().. even though I am trying to call nextcard() [in the print("correct") case]

Which brings me to my question: Can each QPushButton do only one action? I want it to inform the user (or force them to enter the correct answer) before moving on to the next word. Essentially I want one button to call the checkanswer() function as well as the nextword() method at different times.

Here is the code for my main window.. If you need any more information let me know and I will add it here.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    textvalue = ""
    cardnum = 0                                                     # intialize card number from 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButtonEnter.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer)
        self.show()

    def checkanswer(self):
        textvalue = self.ui.lineEditAnswer.text()
        print("You entered: " + textvalue + " $? " + deck[self.cardnum].deflist[0])
        if textvalue == deck[self.cardnum].deflist[0]:
            print("Correct!")
            self.ui.lineEditAnswer.clear()
            textvalue = ""
            self.ui.labelVocab.setText("Correct!\n " + deck[self.cardnum].deflist[0])
            self.ui.pushButtonEnter.setText("Continue")
            self.ui.pushButtonEnter.clicked.connect(self.nextword)
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
            print(self.cardnum)
            self.ui.lineEditAnswer.clear()
            self.ui.labelVocab.setText("Oops! Correct answer is: " + deck[self.cardnum].deflist[0])

    def nextword(self):
        self.cardnum += 1
        self.ui.lineEditAnswer.clear()
        self.ui.pushButtonEnter.setText("Enter")
        self.ui.labelVocab.setText(deck[self.cardnum].vocab)
        self.ui.pushButtonEnter.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        deck = parser.parser()
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        win = MainWindow()
        win.show()
        win.ui.labelVocab.setText(deck[MainWindow.cardnum].vocab)

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work by checking if there was an input and only running the checkanswer() function if textvalue != ""
but that doesn't change the fact that every push of this button will cause it to call the function. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: _Can each QPushButton do only one action?_ No. You can connect multiple signal handlers to every signal (including the `clicked` of push button). If you want to replace a signal handler, you have to disconnect the old before connecting the new.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and it seems to have worked. I wish you would have posted as an answer so I can flag it as the answer. I can't believe I haven't considered disconnecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there is a nice introduction in the Qt doc.:

### [Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

which I warmly recommend to read.

Somewhere in the middle, you find the following paragraph:

> By default, for every connection you make, a signal is emitted; two signals are emitted for duplicate connections. You can break all of these connections with a single [disconnect()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect) call. If you pass the [Qt::UniqueConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) type, the connection will only be made if it is not a duplicate. If there is already a duplicate (exact same signal to the exact same slot on the same objects), the connection will fail and connect will return `false`.

I must admit, I was not aware about the single `disconnect()`. Usually, I store the connection for a signal handler which is returned by `connect()` when I intend to disconnect it later. Furthermore, Qt allows also to disconnect a handler by the same arguments which were given in `connect()` but I never have used this.

Here my little Python sample for fiddling:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
qBtn1 = QPushButton("Click me")
qBtn1.show()

def onBtn1Clicked():
  print("onBtn1Clicked")
  qBtn1.clicked.disconnect()
  qBtn1.setText("Click me again")
  qBtn1.clicked.connect(onBtn1ClickedAgain)

def onBtn1ClickedAgain():
  print("onBtn1ClickedAgain")
  qBtn1.clicked.disconnect()
  qBtn1.setText("Click me")
  qBtn1.clicked.connect(onBtn1Clicked)

qBtn1.clicked.connect(onBtn1Clicked)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The signal handlers `onBtn1Clicked()` and `onBtn1ClickedAgain()` connect each other mutual exclusive.

Tested in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.6.4

$ ./testQPushButton.py
onBtn1Clicked
onBtn1ClickedAgain
onBtn1Clicked
onBtn1ClickedAgain
```

[image: Snapshot of testQPushButton.py] [image: Snapshot of testQPushButton.py after clicking button]

Concerning the multiple calls of a signal handler, I recommend the following: comment the line `qBtn1.clicked.disconnect()` in both handlers and see what happens (on console).

Answer (score 1):

As **Scheff** as pointed out in the comments, you can call the `pushButton.disconnect()` method and then connect `clicked` to another action. 
This is how I fixed my code:

`self.ui.pushButtonEnter.disconnect()
    self.ui.pushButtonEnter.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer)`